# plugin doesn't show after deployment in the eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created an eclipse plugin and it works fine when I'm running it using run as eclipse application.But when I deployed my plugin in the eclipse using File->Export->Deployable plugins and fragments, I cannot see it under new wizard.
I can see my plugin under installed plugins.

Any help why I cannot see it under new wizard list?

UPDATE:

My plugin shows under plugin registry view and when I'm diagnosing it says "no problems detected".
Can anyone help why it's not visible?

Comment: You probably need to start Eclipse with the -clean option to get it to rebuild the extension point cache.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I start Eclipse with -clean option?

Comment: Open a command prompt and run `eclipse -clean` or edit the eclipse.ini and add a line containing `-clean` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Ran Eclipse with -clean option but still cannot see the plugin under new wizard list.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often this is due to a missing dependency.

- Check the "Plug-in Registry" View of your Eclipse installation for your Plug-In.
- Right click on any plugin and check "Show Advanced Options".
- Search your plugin, right click it and clcik on "Diagnose".

It should show you missing dependencies, if there are any.

[image: Just like this]

Comment: I followed what you said. But it says " No problems detected."